# CrystalReports en .NET 'El nombre del archivo del informe estaba vacío'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Quiero generar un documento PDF con Crystal Reports para .NET Visual Studio 2017 pero a la hora de cargar el archivo me sale la siguiente excepción:

CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: 'El nombre del archivo del informe esta vacío.'

He revisado el documento report .rpt y esta bien.

El código que tengo para cargar el report es el siguiente:

```
crs.ReportDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "Documentos\\MiDocumento.rpt");
```

También he probado a cambiarlo con:

```
crs.ReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Documentos\\MiDocumento.rpt"));
```

He comprobado las rutas y están bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que te falta declarar e instanciar un nuevo objeto ReportDocument.

Tengo este código y me funciona perfecto:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument crs = new  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

crs.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Documentos/MiDocumento.rpt"));
```

Saludos!

Comment: lo tengo instanciado de esta manera : using CrystalDecisions.Shared y luego CrystalReportSource crs = new CrystalReportSource() pero no funciona.

Comment: Lo he puesto como lo tienes tu me carga el load para mas adelante en el código necesito hacer un crs.DataBind()  y no me reconoce el DataBind()

Comment: Yo lo hago cargando un Datatable y asignandoselo como Datasource, algo así mirá:

`DataTable tablas = //Cargo el datatable con todos los campos


crystalReport.SetDataSource(tablas);


string ret ="C:/temp/ImpresionTest.pdf";


crystalReport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, ret);`

Comment: Al final puse el código tal y como me comentastes sin el crs.Reportdocument.load() usando solo crs.load()